# Keeps caching ramdomly

Tags: magento2

im having a really strange issue, in my online store i applied some catalogue rules and is working fine. The problem is in the product details page. When the catalog rule is applied normally i run indexer and clear magento cache, and the price shows correcly. But after some time, the price shows wrong, in my case is in the configurable product, in the select box with the simple products shows the wrong price, but is fixed when i click the magento cache clear.

The problem with this is that this keeps sometimes go back again the the old price without the discount rule, to fix it i need to click the button in the cache management always and always.

I have all cache enabled in production mode.

The only thing that can occure to me is the cron jobs, maybe something is happening that makes this go back or something, is someone had the same experience?

Im not using web proxy (secure) if this ocurred, everything looks normal.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried in incognito mode of your browser? It might be because of your browser's cache. If it doesn't work this way, see your overwritten layout.xml files (catalog_product_view) and remove "cachable=true" in the blocks.